# ¿Cómo adaptar estilo de temperatura y, humedad en grafica ChartJS o HighCharts?

Tags: chart.js, highcharts

He logrado obtener una referencia entre datos de temperatura y, humedad sin embargo las columnas de temperatura se muestran del lado izquierdo y, no separadas, es decir una a lado izquierdo y, la otra de lado derecho.

Este el código:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'A',
      yAxisID: 'A',
      data: [100, 96, 84, 76, 69]
    }, {
      label: 'B',
      yAxisID: 'B',
      data: [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'A',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'left',
        scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Humidity'
      }
      }, {
        id: 'B',
        type: 'linear',
        position: 'right',
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Temperature'
        },
        ticks: {
          max: 1,
          min: 0
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.2/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-dnUg2JxjlVoXHVdSMWDYm2Y5xcIrJg1N+juOuRi0yLVkku/g26rwHwysJDAMwahaDfRpr1AxFz43ktuMPr/l1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div style="width:75%;">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Lo que deseo lograr es tener un diseño similar a este, como puedo tener un diseño similar, donde se obtenga datos por ejemplo cada hora, cada 30 segundos y, por fechas, esto son los datos que me interesa graficar dado a los datos que obtengo desde los sensores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola muy buenas queria saber si pudiste hacer el grafico que estabas buscando que busco hacer el mismo para saber si me podias orientar.